# concatenar variable de JS en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código y necesito poder concatenar la variable data.id como lo tengo de ejemplo en el texto de la etiqueta a, ya que es un segundo parámetro que recibe dicha ruta (Trabajando con Laravel) el problema se genera por las llaves, pero no logro poder concatenar dicha variable

```
mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="{{ route('user.edit', ) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">hola'+data.id+'</a>'
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahora mismo la cadena no es válida (algo que se puede ver en el coloreado del código que compartes). Deberías escapar las comillas simples que tienes dentro de otras comillas simples:

```
mRender: function (data, type, row) {
    return '<a href="' + {{ route('user.edit', 1) }} + '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">hola'+data.id+'</a>'
}
```

Comment: pero si yo le paso una constante no me genera ningún tipo de error, lo que necesito escapar es la constante que ves ahí por el data.id

`return '<a href="{!! route('user.edit', 1 ) !!}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">hola'+data.id+'</a>'`

Comment: @yeyoguzmancito cierto, lo he cambiado, aunque no sé si se ajustaría bien a lo que quieres. Si no, borraré la respuesta

Comment: No te apresures, ya lo solucioné. gracias

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

si el código que nos muestras esta dentro de algún documento js creo que el sistema de plantillas que usas no lo modificara nunca.

Pero en el documento de la pagina donde cargas tu script podrías incrustar algo como

```
<html>
<head>
.....
<script>var rutaUsuario = {{ route('user.edit', ) }} ;
</script><script src="miscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

y en el documento js

```
mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="'+rutaUsuarioID+'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">hola'+data.id+'</a>'
                }
```

Comment: Tienes razón compañero, no lo hice por script directo en la vista, enruté un archivo JS y ahora sí funciona. Gracias

Comment: Si estas usando angular, o algo parecido(que no me di cuenta) y la función que estas llamando de "Route" no la resuelve PHP,  la respuesta correcta es que no estabas escapando correctamente las comillas como te mencionan en la respuesta de abajo y deberías darle el crédito.